# Switched from query_posts to wp_query, pagination no longer working

Tags: wp-query, pagination, customization

Switching a loop on a static front page from query_posts to wp_query. All is working other than the pagination link (which used to work). Example can be seen live [here](http://mtthwbsh.com) in "work" section.

Here is my loop:

```
    <?php
     $paged = (get_query_var('page')) ? get_query_var('page') : 1;
     $args = array('category_name'=>'portfolio','posts_per_page'=>4,'paged'=>$paged);
     $work_posts = new WP_Query($args);

     if($work_posts->have_posts()) : 
        while($work_posts->have_posts()) : 
           $work_posts->the_post();
    ?>

        <div class="box">
        <div class="thumbnail">
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
            <?php
                if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
                the_post_thumbnail();
                }   
            ?>  
            </a>
        </div><!-- THUMBNAIL -->        
        <aside>
          <h4><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h4>
        </aside><!-- ASIDE -->
        </div><!-- BOX -->

    <?php endwhile; ?>
  </div><!-- WORK ITEMS -->

  <div class="navigation">
    <div class="older">
      <?php next_posts_link('load more'); ?>
    </div>
  </div>

  <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

    <?php else : ?>
        <h2>Sorry, there are no posts to display</h2>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the example on [`next_posts_link` in Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/next_posts_link#Usage_when_querying_the_loop_with_WP_Query). You have to pass the `max_num_pages` to the function, otherwise it uses the value from the global `$wp_query`, which is no longer the correct query object now that you've created a custom query object.

```
next_posts_link( 'load more', $work_posts->max_num_pages );
```

Comment: This worked perfectly. Not sure how I missed that in the codex, thanks!